# Include PyQt in an installer

Tags: python, qt, installation, pyqt, pyinstaller

I created a python module which uses PyQt.

I would my application to automatically install PyQt on the computer if it is not already there. I also want my module to become an executable - cross platform.

I looked into some other question on this topic and only found that I should use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create my cross platform executable. But i only saw an option for a single file, not a module (I use a directory with `__main__.py` inside as a module)

How can I achieve this?

**I use python 3.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) which supports python 3.3, it also packs up PyQt with the app perfectly.

I ran it on my `__main__.py` file in order to compile the entire module.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [example](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Recipe/DjangoApplication) on the official site for Django module.  You need to specify the file which contains the entry point of your application (`__main__` code):

```
python pyinstaller.py myproject/module/entry_point.py
```

PyInstaller should do the rest automagically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what about the pyqt part? how can I automatically install it on the computer if it is not there?

Comment: According to the official docs PyQt will be included as well (with [some glitches on OSX](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/PyInstallerOnMacOSX)).

Comment: I tried it, it creates a runnable file but it seems it does this only for linux (i'm on linux), how can i get the `exe`? and when i run the executable it says `Python library not found. Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: You can't create executables for the other platforms, i.e. create Windows .exe from Linux.  You have to create each one separately on a specific platform.

Comment: What shows `ldd <your_binary>`?  [It shouldn't list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/pyinstaller/LtBIukEAluc/fsx5jdy61BsJ) Python library included, instead it loads Python dynamically.  Perhaps your script requires Python version higher than installed?

Comment: As my question says, i'm using python 3.3